# How do I make 10 gauge concrete mesh flat for trellises in a garden?

Tags: concrete, gardening

I'm going to be using concrete mesh for a trellis for my plants in the garden this year, and was wondering how I should make them flat, and bend them? I'll also be making tomato cages out of it, so I will need to bend the mesh into place, and make it "hookable" so they can hold each other up also.

Comment: That's the stuff I was planning to use, but also use it for panels, and bend it to hook the rings to the flat pieces, stretch it into rows (similar to corn), then bend hooks into the ends. The question is "how", not "what".

Comment: those holes are too small, I've already looked into it, and it seems a little short also..